# Identify fuse that is off/bad but not tripped

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a set of outlets and an overhead light in the garage that are not powered. I believe I know the fuse they are under via simple labels and from some process of elimination. The fuse is not tripped. When I flip it on and off, it feels just as 'tight' and snaps into place just as the others do that are working. I hope to make sure this is not something super simple before having an electrician come out.

How can I verify that I have the correct one located?

Comment: Breakers trip. Fuses burn out.  ;-)

Comment: Craig, consider yourself lucky if you have never had a breaker burn on you.  As far as the question, if you have plugged a known good light into one of the outlets, and it does not work, after turning the breaker on and off, all that tells you is that there is something not connected. The breaker might be bad, a wire could have come loose from the breaker, or anywhere else in the circuit. If you have turned the breaker off and on, there is not really anything else you can do without starting to open things up.

Comment: It's all fun and games until a circuit breaker catches on fire, huh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To verify you have the correct one, turn off every other breaker one at a time and confirm that it controls whatever it says it does. By process of elimination, you can be fairly certain which breaker controls your garage because there should be one breaker that doesn't seem to control anything.

Thoroughly check your garage for a tripped GFCI outlet. It used to be common for an outlet in the garage to be a GFCI outlet that would protect all the bathroom and kitchen outlets, or all of the exterior outlets. The overhead lighting should not be protected by the GFCI, but I've seen stranger things.

Comment: This.  I had a GFCI outlet behind my microwave that tripped, and I couldn't for the life of me figure out what happened.  I was without power in my kitchen for days, until my uncle happened to suggest pulling out all the appliances, and, voila, working kitchen!

Comment: Yep, it was a GFCI hidden behind stuff on a shelf. Little red light was laughing at me. Thanks all!

Comment: Hah. That alone (GFCI outlet hidden behind an appliance) is a good argument for using GFCI breakers now that the price has dropped down under $40.